# PageObjects: Aggregation/Composition vs Inheritance for nested components

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-design, page-objects

I need to refactor my Selenium tests, and was wondering what the best design solution would be for a portal with a hierarchical page organization. We are using [tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/), and we have defined a baselayout from which many pages inherit.

Consider the following simplified example:

1. baselayout

   - start
   - about

What would be better, an inherited based design:

```
/** Implements methods that access the top-level menu. */
Class BaseLayout {...}

/** Implements methods that access elements of the "Start" page */
Class StartPage extends Base Layout {...}

/** Implements methods that access elements of the "About" page */
Class AboutPage extends Base Layout {...}
```

or an aggregation based design?:

```
/** Implements methods that access the top-level menu. */
Class BaseLayout {...}

/** Implements methods that access elements of the "Start" page */
Class StartPage {
    BaseLayout parent;
    // ...
}

/** Implements methods that access elements of the "About" page */
Class AboutPage {
    BaseLayout parent;
    // ...
}
```

The question arose when I came across the [LoadableComponent design pattern](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent), as Selenium already provides an abstract class for such components, thus making the first inheritance-based solution unfeasible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the inherited based design. It worked great until the application I'm testing was also made available in another, more limited customer-facing UI. So now I have two applications which consist of the same components surrounded by different menus. That's a situation where the inherited design breaks.

An aggregation-based design combined with some IOC container could be a lot more flexible, I guess.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'll try to figure out how to combine it with IOC as you mention.

Comment: @Alberto I'm currently asking myself the same question and after seeing Ivo's response I'm starting to think he's right. I was wondering if you could share with me how you ended up implementing it and what were the problems you found. Thank you!

Comment: @Mario I'd probably disappoint you, but at the end, I didn't find useful the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.LoadableComponent`. We also don't have (up to now) any web component included into more than one page, so the inheritance-based design works well. If things change in the future, I can always rewrite the `PageObject`s of the reused components to be aggregated into their `PageObject` containers.